# Show message or run script on first login after reboot of ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

essentially I would like to make sure I mount an encrypted drive after each reboot of my ubuntu server. Since this obviously requires me to type in my password, there are two ways I can imagine this to work:

- either show a message on each first log in of my user following a reboot (basically a reminder), or
- automatically running a script on each first log in of my user following a reboot.

Is either of the two possible at all and/or is there another (possibly more elegant) way to achieve this?

Thanks a ton for your advice!
Best,
J

See suggestion below for the first step toward a working solution. Basically, here's what I ended up doing:

1. write script, which checks if device is mounted and execute mounting command if not:

```
mount | grep -c mapper/[device mapper] # this returns 1 if mounted, 0 if not
```

2. Run this as cronjob

Comment: Bonus Q: Why is my introductory "Hello friendly people," always chopped off/deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a script on startup via `cron`.
Simply run `crontab -e` to create a cron-table. (It will create an empty one if you don't already have one.)

To run your script on startup, use

`@reboot     /home/user/script_at_reboot.sh`.

Further documentation [in the ubuntu wiki.](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron/)

Comment: Just came back here to edit my question and make just that suggestion. Thanks for your help @fr3dch3n! For sake of completion I'll edit my post with a working script in case anybody else might stumble upon this.